# nginx regex with capture bug

Tags: nginx, regex, headers

I'm trying to use regex capture functions for create an `Access-Control-Origin header`.

So y have two main capture, one for the adress of website ( like`http://example.com`)
and another for the port user (such as `:4200`).

The idea is having this header : `Origin: http://example.com:4200`

My capture work for the first case but it seem to don't like the port.

I get `Origin : http://example.com:` instead of `Origin: http://example.com:4200`

Here is my nginx config :

My guess is that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` don't understant numerical value.

```
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/api/blabla/*){
          set $public "1";
    }

    if ($http_origin ~* (https?:\/\/[^/]*(localhost|\.example.com))(:[0-9]+)?[^\w\d]) {
         set $public "${public}1";
    } 
    if ($public = "11"){
         set $http_origin_regex $1$4;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin_regex";
    }
```

Comment: you have `()(` in `(https?:\/\/[^/]*()(localhost`. it looks wrong

Comment: Oh, we got a typo ! 
But it still does not work :/

Comment: `$http_origin ~* ^https?://[^/]*(localhost:|\.example\.com)(:[0-9]+)$`

Comment: There are many online tools for checking your regular expressions and how their captures work. They are really useful in debugging.

Comment: I've already check this part. the capture is totally working these website but not in nginx

Answer (score 0):

look at http://marcel.zurreck.com/enable-cross-origin-requests-cors-nginx/

using their syntax I got:

```
location ~ ^/api/blabla/ {
    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://[^/]*(localhost|\.example\.com)(:[0-9]+)?)) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    }
}
```